# Laravel - Post to external API with resources?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have to post from my Laravel App (version 6) to an external API.
I have to do some data transformation to accomplish the data structure and values expected from external API.

It's Laravel Resources and Guzzle client the solution for this type of requirement? Other approach I'm considering as I have my app in GCP services, is to use a cloud function to call an API from my Laravel App, tranform data in cloud function and post to external API but this approach looks more complex than a pure Laravel approach.

If any one can share any approach it will be great!

Regards

Comment: Guzzle client and Resources can work great. I prefer https://github.com/spatie/data-transfer-object over built in resources, myself. Not exactly the same, but accomplish a lot of the same things. For more info: https://sandulat.com/moving-from-laravel-api-resources-to-dtos/

Comment: If it's a direct communication from your Laravel app and the external API then yes, the Guzzle + Resources approach should be the most straightforward way to do it.

Comment: @SohelAman so you recommend to create JSON data with resources and after pass that data to Guzzle Client and call post to external API? That't the flow you recommend?

Comment: Thanks @KurtFriars
This looks a good approach too! Why do you recommend DTO and not resources? Just because you are used to DTO or resources don't offer the same level of data transformation?

Comment: I actually have extended the package, and plan to make a PR in the future. I was using Laravel's API resources, and there were aspects that felt frustrating. I had started using DTOs for other parts of my application and found they were capable of handling all the cases where I would use API Resources. TBH the bigges benefit IMO is the "built in" documentation via type hinting everything. When you are working with Spatie DTOs in an IDE with code intelligence, it is a true pleasure.

Comment: Yes. Mainly because of two simple design choices. First, the data seems to reside at the Laravel app. So, it makes more sense to process it here and directly call the external API with it. Second, I do not see any reason to involve a middle layer (cloud function) to fetch data from Laravel, process, and then call the external API. This complicates the process by adding an additional (fetch) request and another code segment that you have to manage separately.